# Aggregate List displaying Repeating values

Tags: apex, visualforce, list, aggregate

All Apex experts!

I am correctly displaying an Aggregate Result set from 3 distinct Salesforce Objects.

However I am seeing an issue with repeating values on my Visualforce component with these 2 items on my list:

```
result.add( new CoverageTeamMember( 'Producer', account.Producer__r.Id, account.Producer__r.Name, account.Producer__r.Email__c, account.Producer__r.Work_Phone__c) );

result.add( new CoverageTeamMember( 'Client Owner', account.Serv1__r.Id, account.Serv1__r.Name, account.Serv1__r.Email__c,account.Serv1__r.Work_Phone__c ) );
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong here!  Greatly appreciate the help removing repeating entries!

```
public with sharing class SL_ctrl_AccountCoverageTeam_comp {

private final ApexPages.StandardController controller;
public String accountId {get;set;}

public SL_ctrl_AccountCoverageTeam_comp() { 
    //accountId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
}

public List<CoverageTeamMember> getCoverageTeam() {
Account a = getAccount(this.controller != null ? this.controller.getId() : accountId);
    List<CoverageTeamMember> l = getCoverageTeam(a);
    l.addAll(getClaimsCoverageTeam(a));
return l;
}

//Account query to get Servicer 1 & 2
private Account getAccount( ID account ) {
    return [ SELECT Producer__r.Name, Producer__r.Email__c, Producer__r.Work_Phone__c, Servicer_1__c, Serv1__r.Name, Serv1__r.Email__c, Serv1__r.Work_Phone__c, Servicer_2__c FROM Account WHERE Id = :account ];
}

//Policy query to get Active Policy Coverage Team Members
private List<CoverageTeamMember> getCoverageTeam( Account account ) {
    List<CoverageTeamMember> result = this.getStaticCoverageTeam( account );

    for ( AggregateResult records : [ 
        SELECT Servicer_Department_Name__c role, Servicer__r.Id name, Servicer__r.Name actualname, Servicer__r.Email__c email, Servicer__r.Work_Phone__c phone, Active__c a
        FROM Policy__c
        WHERE Account__c = :account.Id AND 
            Servicer_Department_Name__c != null AND
            Servicer__c != null AND
            Active__c = True
        GROUP BY Servicer_Department_Name__c, Servicer__r.Id, Servicer__r.Name, Servicer__r.Email__c, Servicer__r.Work_Phone__c, Active__c
    ] ) {
        result.add( new CoverageTeamMember( records ) );
    }

    return result;
}

//Claims query to get Active Claims Coverage Team Members
private List<CoverageTeamMember> getClaimsCoverageTeam( Account account ) {
    List<CoverageTeamMember> result = this.getStaticCoverageTeam( account );

    for ( AggregateResult claims : [ 
        SELECT Servicer_Department_Name__c role, Servicer__r.Id name, Servicer__r.Name actualname, Servicer__r.Email__c email, Servicer__r.Work_Phone__c phone, IsClosed__c a
        FROM Claim__c 
        WHERE Account__c = :account.Id AND 
            Servicer_Department_Name__c != null AND
            Servicer__c != null AND
            IsClosed__c = False
        GROUP BY Servicer_Department_Name__c, Servicer__r.Id, Servicer__r.Name, Servicer__r.Email__c, Servicer__r.Work_Phone__c, IsClosed__c
    ] ) {
        result.add( new CoverageTeamMember( claims ) );
    }

    return result;
}

private List<CoverageTeamMember> getStaticCoverageTeam( Account account ) {
    List<CoverageTeamMember> result = new List<CoverageTeamMember>();
    result.add( new CoverageTeamMember( 'Producer', account.Producer__r.Id, account.Producer__r.Name, account.Producer__r.Email__c, account.Producer__r.Work_Phone__c) );
    result.add( new CoverageTeamMember( 'Client Owner', account.Serv1__r.Id, account.Serv1__r.Name, account.Serv1__r.Email__c,account.Serv1__r.Work_Phone__c ) );
    return result;
}

public class CoverageTeamMember {
public final String role { get; set; }
public final String name { get; set; }
public final String actualname { get; set; }
public final String email { get; set; }
public final String phone { get; set; } 


public CoverageTeamMember( AggregateResult records) {
    this( String.valueOf( records.get( 'role' ) ), 
    String.valueOf( records.get( 'name' ) ), 
    String.valueOf( records.get( 'actualname' ) ),
    String.valueOf( records.get( 'email' ) ), 
    String.valueOf( records.get( 'phone') ) );
}

public CoverageTeamMember( String role, String name, String actualname, String email, String phone) {
    this.role = role;
    this.name = name;
    this.actualname = actualname;
    this.email = email;
    this.phone = phone;
}
}
}
```

[image: dupe]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the same `Servicer__c` object may be referenced from the two queries.

One solution is to modify the logic to also capture `Servicer__r.Id` in the aggregate queries and to store that in the `CoverageTeamMember` class (in a field called say `servicerId`). Then you can discard the duplicates at the end of the `getCoverageTeam` method:

```
...
l.addAll(getClaimsCoverageTeam(a)); 

Set<Id> ids = new Set<Id>();
List<CoverageTeamMember> ll = new List<CoverageTeamMember>();
for (CoverageTeamMember ctm : l) {
    if (!ids.contains(ctm.servicerId)) {
        ll.add(l);
        ids.add(ctm.servicerId);
    }
}
return ll;
```

**PS**

Based on the comments the above isn't right. Instead moving the pieces into one method might be the simplest way to go:

```
public List<CoverageTeamMember> getCoverageTeam() {

    Account account = getAccount(this.controller != null ? this.controller.getId() : accountId);

    // Add Producer and Client Owner once
    List<CoverageTeamMember> result = this.getStaticCoverageTeam(account);

    // Policy query to get Active Policy Coverage Team Members
    for ( AggregateResult records : [ 
        SELECT Servicer_Department_Name__c role, Servicer__r.Id name, Servicer__r.Name actualname, Servicer__r.Email__c email, Servicer__r.Work_Phone__c phone, Active__c a
        FROM Policy__c
        WHERE Account__c = :account.Id AND 
            Servicer_Department_Name__c != null AND
            Servicer__c != null AND
            Active__c = True
        GROUP BY Servicer_Department_Name__c, Servicer__r.Id, Servicer__r.Name, Servicer__r.Email__c, Servicer__r.Work_Phone__c, Active__c
    ] ) {
        result.add( new CoverageTeamMember( records ) );
    }

    // Claims query to get Active Claims Coverage Team Members
    for ( AggregateResult claims : [ 
        SELECT Servicer_Department_Name__c role, Servicer__r.Id name, Servicer__r.Name actualname, Servicer__r.Email__c email, Servicer__r.Work_Phone__c phone, IsClosed__c a
        FROM Claim__c 
        WHERE Account__c = :account.Id AND 
            Servicer_Department_Name__c != null AND
            Servicer__c != null AND
            IsClosed__c = False
        GROUP BY Servicer_Department_Name__c, Servicer__r.Id, Servicer__r.Name, Servicer__r.Email__c, Servicer__r.Work_Phone__c, IsClosed__c
    ] ) {
        result.add( new CoverageTeamMember( claims ) );
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: The issue I am seeing is with these 2 repeating values that are pulled from the Account object.  I suppose I'm not clear on what this has to do with Servicer__c.

Comment: result.add( new CoverageTeamMember( 'Producer', account.Producer__r.Id, account.Producer__r.Name, account.Producer__r.Email__c, account.Producer__r.Work_Phone__c) );

result.add( new CoverageTeamMember( 'Client Owner', account.Serv1__r.Id, account.Serv1__r.Name, account.Serv1__r.Email__c,account.Serv1__r.Work_Phone__c ) );

Comment: @SFDCCrystalCo OK I misunderstood. Another attempt in the PS.

Comment: That did the trick!  Cheers to you @KeithC!  Where should I send the beers?